# get the attributed string from uitextview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I need to get the attributed string from UITextView. For example if user has formatted the text to bold or italic i need to save in variable or display in label as it is. Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking here, but UITextView has an `attributedText` property, so you can just get this by doing:

```
yourTextView.attributedText
```

Remember that an attributed string doesn't have only one attribute for the whole string (like an NSString), but depending on the index, it can have different attributes (so the first word can be in bold, and the second one can be italic).

To retrieve an attribute on a given index you can use the following property:

```
attributedString.attribute("your attribute", atIndex: yourIndex, effectiveRange: yourRange)
```

You can see more ways of accessing the attributes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/AccessingAttrs.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could do so:

```
UITextView *txtView;
UILabel *label;
self.label.attributedText = self.txtView.attributedText;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works but i need to save attributed string in a variable to pass on another ViewController. So how to do that?

Comment: This is how you store attributed string: NSAttributedString *str = self.txtView.attributedText;

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked for you so that other can also use the solution.